# Postfix ignore relayhost for specific source servers (localhost)

Tags: postfix

Postfix is setup for

```
relayhost = spamfilter.example.com:25
```

I have a few php scripts running on the same server as postfix that send emails via the mail command (sendmail) to various email addresses (example@gmail.com). Is it possible to ignore the relayhost for mail originating from 127.0.0.1? I'd like the server to attempt delivery directly instead of relaying to our spam filter (spamfilter.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change the transport ([`sender_dependent_default_transport_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_default_transport_maps)) or relayhost ([`sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_relayhost_maps)) used depending on sender envelope address. If the PHP scripts are run as different users than mail users, this is a very suitable solution.

In your PHP script you can even set envelope sender and `From:` address separate using 5th optional parameter to give envelope sender directly to Sendmail:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,'-f envelope@example.com');
```